# Anonymous Access to Web Parts

Tags: web-parts

I have created one web application and I have hosted on test(IIS 6) and main server(IIS 7) but I am not able use the Edit, catalogue and design mode in Anonymous Access.

It is working fine when I set Integrate Windows Authentication to true. At that time I am able to make the changes on page.

But in Integrate Windows Authentication whenever I access the link windows asking me to enter the test server user name and password for authentication.

please can anyone tell me how to make it working on Anonymous access mode.

Awaiting reply....